# Install4j error. "This application requires a newer version of Java runtime"

Tags: java, windows, install4j

I have this strange behavior of installation and launcher. I created Windows install which installs application. However when I try to launch it then window "JavaFX Launcher" with message "This application requires a newer version of the Java runtime. Please download and install the latest Java runtime from java.com. Then restart the application."

I believe it has something to do with minimum  Java Version and maximum Java version settings in install4j. I have JRE 1.8.0_40 installed and I set 1.7 as minimum java version during install4j installation and statically bundled JRE 1.8.0_40 into installation.

I am able to install application, but when I try to launch it I get this "This application requires a newer version of the Java runtime..." message.
It's the same if I don't bundle JRE or set maximum java version higher. But it works when a set both java min version and java max version to 1.7 (even though I don't have java 1.7 neither as my installed JRE nor bundled with install).

In general it doesn't make sense "This application requires a newer version of the Java runtime" when you have latest JRE installed (and the same latest bundled).

Would be very appreciated for some help here

Comment: Ho do you call your main method? Please do not use any intermediary JavaFX main methods as in JavaFX 1, but call your main method directly.

Comment: Well. I believe install4j  creates Windows launcher that calls com.javafx.main.Main directly.

Comment: No, you specify the main class yourself in the launcher wizard. Calling  com.javafx.main.Main instead of your main class will lead to this error message.